# Not able to read large RDF file

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I have large 30GB .nt file in RDF format. When I am parsing that file through jena library I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.jena.riot.tokens.TokenizerText.parseToken(TokenizerText.java:170)
at org.apache.jena.riot.tokens.TokenizerText.hasNext(TokenizerText.java:86)
at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.PeekIterator.fill(PeekIterator.java:50)
at org.apache.jena.atlas.iterator.PeekIterator.next(PeekIterator.java:92)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.nextToken(LangEngine.java:101)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.parseOne(LangNTriples.java:75)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.runParser(LangNTriples.java:58)
at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:42)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:176)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:862)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:260)
at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:246)
at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.RDFReaderRIOT.read(RDFReaderRIOT.java:69)
at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:281)
at rdfRead.RdfDataRead.main(RdfDataRead.java:77)
... 5 more
```

I had given 20GB memory through Xmx command. I have max 25GB ram. 
SO is there any way to read GBs of file? So that it doesn't load all the data in memory.

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your post and be a lot more descriptive? Maybe post an excerpt of your code?

Comment: could you also show the code which you are using . I am not sure but there might be a issue with model.read() or the way you are using

Comment: try loading it into a database (e.g. TDB) rather than parse to memory.

Comment: post your code in order to reproduce the problem